# Getting an "implicit declaration of function" error in Code Blocks

Tags: c, gcc, c11, tr24731

I am still quite new to C, and I keep getting an error in Code Blocks which stops me from running my programs. I get the error "implicit declaration of functions printf_s() and scanf_s(). Here is my code:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int age = 0;
  char name[20];

  printf_s("Enter your age: ");
  scanf_s("%d", &age);

  print_s("Enter your name: ");
  scanf_s("%s", name, sizeof(name));

  printf_s("Your name is %s and you are %d years old.\n", name, age);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are learning, don't use non standard functions. Which OS is this?

Comment: Hey everyone.. if you haven't seen something before, it doesn't mean it is non-standard

Comment: `scanf_s` and `printf_s` are MS specific prior to C11, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

`printf_s` and `scanf_s` are only available if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined by the library implementation. It is added since C11 standard.

First you have to check `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined or not, then only you should use `printf_s` or `scanf_s`.

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int age = 0;
  char name[20];
  #ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
      printf_s("Enter your age: ");
      scanf_s("%d", &age);
      print_s("Enter your name: ");
      scanf_s("%s", name, sizeof(name));
      printf_s("Your name is %s and you are %d years old.\n", name, age);
  #else
      printf("Enter your age: ");
      scanf("%d", &age);
      print("Enter your name: ");
      scanf("%19s", name);
      printf("Your name is %s and you are %d years old.\n", name, age);
  #endif
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The features you are using are "optional" according to the ISO C Standard.

Apparently, the compiler/library bundled with Code::Blocks does not implement this option.  So your choices now are:

- Don't use the features
- Use a compiler which does implement this option
- Use conditional code as shown in jblixr's answer

Also, you could log a feature request with MinGW (or MinGW-w64).

Why does the C Standard include optional functions? Typically this is the result of political processes; one faction on the standards committee wanted the feature and another didn't, so the compromise is to make the feature optional.  Another example of this is variable-length arrays.

Answer (score -2):

Standard function names have no `_s` so the standard compliant version of the program would be

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int age = 0;
  char name[20];

  printf("Enter your age: ");
  scanf("%d", &age);

  print("Enter your name: ");
  scanf("%19s", name);

  printf("Your name is %s and you are %d years old.\n", name, age);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know the _s is pretty unnecessary here, but the book is forcing me to use the _s for future reference. I still need to fix the error.

Comment: Ok, read another book. You are likely using a compiler that expects standard code. Standard code SHOULD compile on any compiler while this variation the book is teaching you requires a specific compiler AFAIK, the MS C++ compiler (*it does compile [tag:c] code but it does not differentiate between the languages I think*). If the book is forcing you to learn that it's IMHO not a good book. A good book would teach the basics and standards only. Giving you freedom to choose when you gain experience.